# Output argument not assigned on some execution paths

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I am trying to run MATLAB Coder to transform a MATLAB .m file into .mex to hopefully run the code more quickly. When trying to build the file via MATLAB Coder engine, I get the following error:

```
Output argument 'summstat' is not assigned on some execution paths
```

Where `summstat` is the output argument of the funtion I am trying to compile. In the last line of my code I assign `summstat`:

```
summstat = pinc;
```

where `pinc` is another variable used throughout the code. Most of the problems of this type occur when the output variable is assigned inside an `if` branch, but this is not the case here. Although I do have `if`s and `for`s throughout the code, the assignment is not inside any of these (like I said, it is the last line of the function).

```
function summstat = fun(para,T)
coder.extrinsic('clock');
summstat = 0;
pinc = 0;

prob   = [ .8 .2; .5 .5];

A      = 1.00;

theta  = 0.05;
Kstart = 10.0;
g      = 0.20;


sigma = para(1);
beta = para(2);
delta = para(3);
alpha = para(4);

maxkap = 20;
inckap = 0.025;
nkap   = round(maxkap/inckap+1);



D = zeros(length(prob));
[ev,ed] = eig(prob);
[emax,inmax] = max(diag(ed));
if emax~=1;
   disp('are you sure the matrix prob is correct?');
end;
D(inmax,inmax) = real(emax);

pinf = ev*D*inv(ev);
pempl = pinf(inmax,inmax);
N = 1.0*pempl + theta*(1-pempl);

liter   = 1;
maxiter = 50;
toler   = 0.001;
metric  = 10;
K = Kstart;
Kold = 0;
nstates = size(prob,1);
decis = zeros(nkap,nstates);
rent=0;
wage=0;

while  (metric > toler) & (liter <= maxiter);

   wage = (1-alpha) * A * K^(alpha)   * N^(-alpha);
   rent = (alpha)   * A * K^(alpha-1) * N^(1-alpha);

   util1=-10000*ones(nkap,nkap);
   util2=-10000*ones(nkap,nkap);

   for i=1:nkap;
         kap=(i-1)*inckap;
         for j=1:nkap;
               kapp = (j-1)*inckap;
               cons1 = wage + (rent + delta)*kap - kapp;
               if cons1 > 0;

                  util1(j,i)=real((cons1)^(1-sigma)/(1-sigma));
               end;
           cons2 = theta*wage + (rent + delta)*kap - kapp;
               if cons2 > 0;

                  util2(j,i)=real((cons2)^(1-sigma)/(1-sigma));
               end;
         end;
   end;

   v       = zeros(nkap,2);
   decis   = zeros(nkap,2);
   test    = 10;
   [rs,cs] = size(util1);

   r1=zeros(size(util1(:,1),1),cs);
   r2=zeros(size(util2(:,1),1),cs);
   while test ~= 0;
       for i=1:cs;
           r1(:,i)=util1(:,i)+beta*(prob(1,1)*v(:,1)+ prob(1,2)*v(:,2));
           r2(:,i)=util2(:,i)+beta*(prob(2,1)*v(:,1)+ prob(2,2)*v(:,2));
       end;

       [tv1,tdecis1]=max(r1);
       [tv2,tdecis2]=max(r2);
       tdecis=[tdecis1' tdecis2'];
       tv=[tv1' tv2'];

       test_mex = true;

       test_mex = max(any(tdecis-decis));
       v=tv;
       decis=tdecis;

   end;
   decis=(decis-1)*inckap;

   g2=zeros(cs,cs);
   g1=zeros(cs,cs);

   for i=1:cs
       g1(i,tdecis1(i))=1;
       g2(i,tdecis2(i))=1;
   end
   trans=[ prob(1,1)*g1 prob(1,2)*g1; prob(2,1)*g2 prob(2,2)*g2];
   trans=trans';
   probst = (1/(2*nkap))*ones(2*nkap,1);
   test=1;
   while test > 10^(-8);
      probst1 = trans*probst;
      test = max(abs(probst1-probst));
      probst = probst1;
   end;

   kk=decis(:);
   meanK=probst'*kk;

   lambda=zeros(cs,2);
   lambda(:)=probst;

   [v1,d1]=eig(prob');
   [dmax,imax]=max(diag(d1));
   probst1=v1(:,imax);
   ss=sum(probst1);
   probst1=probst1/ss;
   probk=sum(lambda');
   probk=probk';

   Kold = K;
   Knew = g*meanK + (1-g)*Kold;
   metric = abs((Kold-meanK)/Kold);
   K = Knew;

   liter = liter+1;
end;

grid = [ (0:inckap:maxkap)' ];
    income = zeros(size(grid,1),2);

    income = [real((rent*grid + wage)) real((rent*grid + wage*theta)) ];
 [ pinc, index ] = sort(income(:));

summstat = pinc;

end
```

Comment: Can you post the function? which matlab version are you using?

Comment: Do you have return statements inside your function?

Comment: I have just posted the code, tried a few things but still no success. I dont understand why simply pre-assigning the variable at the beginning of the code does not work...

Comment: If I paste the code into the mfile editor, it gives several warnings, mostly about unused variables. You may want to look into those as well and clean up the code a bit. (If your code looks like `X=zeros(3), X=rand(3)` it seems like you want to use the first formula to preallocate, but it is in general not recommended as the latter formula automatically returns something of the right size)

Comment: I have removed comments since there other portions of code which maybe use these unused variables you mentioned. About the pre-allocation, I am still getting used to what needs to be pre-allocated for mex compilation, so I am still working on that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of an unfortunate message. In short, the issue stems from the fact that the `while` loop with condition:

```
while test ~= 0;
```

is infinite and can be determined to be infinite during code generation. Notice that `test` is set to 10 before the loop and `test` is never written during the loop.

So, in effect, the output will never be written because control will never reach beyond this loop. To test this theory, I added:

```
test = test - 1;
```

inside of that `while` loop and was able to generate code with:

```
codegen fun -args {1:4,1} -report
```

I reported this to the MATLAB Coder team so we can consider improving this case in the future.

For completeness, if an infinite loop is actually desired (e.g. for a server loop), then the function containing it could be written to not have an output since that function will never return.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be a hidden `break` or a `while` that appears to go on forever.

That being said, I can't really spot those in your code, so here is how you can approach the problem.

1. Does the problem disappear if you remove the `summstat = pinc` part?
2. Or if you change it to `summstat = 0`?

Otherwise I would recommend you to start cutting parts of code out untill the error disappears, then you can zoom in on some suspect lines. Perhaps you can start by cutting out everyting EXCEPT `summstat = 0` on the first line, and see whether that works as expected.

Comment: I did try both of those and for 1. and 2. there is no problem; I am able to generate the mex file.  I'll keep at it and see if anythings comes up.